# GetTextExtentPoint32 returning values a little off, glyphs truncated

Tags: winapi, fonts, gdi, typography

For all strings, the GDI function `GetTextExtentPoint32` seems to be returning a width always a little smaller than what `ExtTextOut` displays:

[image: the y is truncated]

Above the right red arrow, "buggy," is displayed as a block with `ExtTextOut`: no problem.

Above the left red arrow, "buggy" is displayed with `ExtTextOut`, then ", " is displayed `width` pixels later, where `width = GetTextExtentPoint32("buggy")`. `width` seems a little too small.

Using bigger font sizes and dark backgrounds:

[image]

Again, "00" and "()" are displayed in different `ExtTextOut` calls with `GetTextExtentPoint32("00")` pixels between them.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that in your selected font, the letter "y" has a negative C-width?

Comment: @Raymond Chen I haven't tried calling GetCharABCWidths so I am not sure but I don't think so, the font (Calibri) is standard and the last character of words is always truncated whatever it is. And shouldn't GetTextExtentPoint32 sort all this out by itself? It supposedly "computes the width and height of the specified string of text" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938(v=vs.85) ...

Comment: I don't know, I'm just guessing.

Comment: I've given up relying on accurate text width measurement a while ago.  Kerning, glyph overhang and TrueType hinting makes it *way* too difficult.  GetTextExtent dates from much simpler times.

Comment: Instead of `GetTextExtent32` and `ExtTextOut`, why don't you use `DrawText`, once with `DT_CALCRECT` and once without?

Comment: @jamesdlin I need to make a text processing/editing engine supporting different fonts/font sizes/font styles etc, DrawText is a much slower, and higher level function which makes adjustments to draw into a rectangle, ExtTextOut seems to be the function to use for low level text rendering. I think DrawText is just not for that kind of use, it's a slow/convenience function.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Surely there must be a way because it's necessary to display text correctly; how else do we know how many pixels to advance after displaying a word? If it wasn't possible, all text in word processors/browsers/everywhere would have artifacts like I have above...

Comment: Sure, Uniscribe is the api for that.  Don't underestimate the difficultly of writing a word processor or browser :)

Comment: @Hans Passant: Ah, I was thinking of using DirectWrite, which http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniscribe says is the intended replacement of Uniscribe, I'll try that if I can't figure it out with GDI. DirectWrite doesn't seem to be much loved though, so I was postponing it and sticking to the tried and true.

Comment: Sure.  DirectWrite is not supported on XP though, in case that matters.

Comment: Don't use DrawText if you want precision. We discovered years ago some drivers don't implement DrawText correctly, returning different values for DT_CALCRECT vs. actual printing. Surprise!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found the same problem dealing with monospaced True Type fonts (Lucida Console) and OPAQUE background mode. The problem seems that you call ExtTextOut with correct x coordinate, but the function paints background starting at x-1, which is something I didn’t expect. Negative shift may be higher on larger font size. Glyphs are finally correctly positioned, but that "overpaint" is a problem unless TRANSPARENT background mode is selected. Previously, I thought that I didn’t need to specify the rc parameter, since I didn’t need clipping at all as all character runs were non overlapping, but eventually I’ve had to provide an apparently redundant RECT and ETO_CLIPPING flag, just to prevent this horizontal negative overpainting.